# How can I define document in electron?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, electron

the other stackoverflow questions I found didn't help me, so I am asking you. How can I define the document in html / javascript in electron. There is the error: ''document is not defined''.

html code:

```
  <div id="container">
      <div id="left_panel"> left content! </div>
      <div id="right_panel">
          <div id="drag"></div> right content!
      </div>
  </div>
```

javascript:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
Menu.setApplicationMenu(false);
var isResizing = false;
var lastDownX = 0;

function boot() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    'minHeight': 300,
    'minWidth': 300
  })
  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: 'index.html',
    slashes: true
  }))
}

app.on('ready', boot);

(function() {
    var container = document.getElementById("container"),
        left = document.getElementById("left_panel"),
        right = document.getElementById("right_panel"),
        handle = document.getElementById("drag");

    handle.onmousedown = function(e) {
        isResizing = true;
        lastDownX = e.clientX;
    };

    document.onmousemove = function(e) {
        // we don't want to do anything if we aren't resizing.
        if (!isResizing) {
            return;
        }

        var offsetRight = container.clientWidth - (e.clientX - container.offsetLeft);

        left.style.right = offsetRight + "px"; 
        right.style.width = offsetRight + "px"; 
    }

    document.onmouseup = function(e) {
        // stop resizing
        isResizing = false;
    }
})();
```

It would be great, if I received help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [executeJavascript](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture) method might be able to help you out here. This allows you to access the document object. It returns a Promise so you will have to pull out your Elements from that.

Comment: i added the code 
 "contents.executeJavaScript('fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1").then(resp => resp.json())', true)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result) // Will be the JSON object from the fetch call
  })", but it does not work or what do i have to do